# Increment new column after insert

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I have a question for all of you. I'm quite new in SQL and searched for more than 2 hours and didn't find exactly what I need.

I'm having a table in SQL named Courses. Here is the constructor:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
(sign     VARCHAR2(6)   NOT NULL,
title     VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
credits   INTEGER       NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  PrimaryKeyCourses  PRIMARY KEY (sign)
);
```

I have to add a new column, which I did with :

```
ALTER TABLE Courses ADD frequency INTEGER;
```

I want to create a **trigger** which will increment every time a new courses is added.

I tried to do this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER fq
AFTER INSERT ON Courses
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE frequency SET frequency = frequency + 1;
```

But it doesn't seems to work properly :( I don't know what to do.

Comment: use sequence instead!!

Comment: @nikhilsugandh for this exercise I have to use a trigger :(

Comment: What do you want to update? The `FREQUENCY` column on the `COURSES` table? And which row in `COURSES` do you want to update when you add a new row to `COURSES` - just the new row (so, set `FREQUENCY` to 1), or all the rows in `COURSES`, or ???

Comment: @BobJarvis I want the newly created column `frequency` to increment for every `INSERT`I do on the table `COURSES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use an `UPDATE` statement, use a `SELECT` statement with `max(value)+1`. And to be able to change a `:new.` value, need to convert trigger to `BEFORE` type.

So, you can use the one as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fq
BEFORE INSERT ON Courses
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    select nvl(max(frequency),0)+1
      into :new.frequency
      from Courses;
END;
```

Of course you need a `commit` after a DML statement, I think it's better to include only one `commit` outside of this trigger after `INSERT` statement applied on `Courses` table, because of providing transaction integrity rule.

*P.S. I know you're restricted to use a trigger, but Using a sequence for the value of column `frequency` is a better, practical alternative as @nikhil sugandh suggested. In this case a trigger is not needed. If you're using DB version 12c, you can add that sequence as default for the column `frequency` as `frequency INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` during the table creation.*

Comment: It says `Trigger created with compilation errors.` when I try to run the script :/

Comment: @GuillaumeLevesque OK I fixed. By the way, it seems `frequency` column only belongs to the `Courses` table, there's not an other individual table called `frequency`, is it?

Comment: Nope! Only this table.

Answer (score 0):

use sequence :

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE Courses_frequency
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

and do insert like:

```
INSERT INTO Courses 
(sign,title,credits,frequency)
VALUES
(value1,value2,value3,Courses_frequency.NEXTVAL);
```